# Getting more metadata about epub documents

Tags: bash, command-line, epub

Without giving more details, the only commands I know are file, stat and mediainfo. While both give some idea about an .epub document, not all. For e.g. file just gives the filename and declares it to be an epub document. Mediainfo is slightly better that it gives the following info.

```
Format                                   : ZIP
File size                                : 93.9 MiB
FileExtension_Invalid                    : zip docx odt xlsx ods
```

So apart from the name of the document, I know the above. The most crucial bits though are missing. When was the epub book published, what version of epub version was used, what app. was used to make the .epub document and so on and so forth. There are so many versions from version 2, 2.0.1, 3, 3.2 and so on. Having all the above info. would make things easier to troubleshoot.

Something on the lines of pdfinfo.

Comment: Try `exiftool` which is the go-to tool to extract file metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `exiftool` which is the go-to tool to extract file metadata:

```
$ exiftool Downloads/accessible_epub_3.epub
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.57
File Name                       : accessible_epub_3.epub
Directory                       : Downloads
File Size                       : 4.1 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:05:05 08:13:22+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2023:05:05 08:13:33+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2023:05:05 08:13:22+01:00
File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
File Type                       : EPUB
File Type Extension             : epub
MIME Type                       : application/epub+zip
Identifier Id                   : pub-identifier
Identifier                      : urn:isbn:9781449328030
Title Id                        : pub-title
Title                           : Accessible EPUB 3
Language Id                     : pub-language
Language                        : en
Date                            : 2012:02:20
Meta Property                   : dcterms:modified
Meta                            : 2012:10:24 15:30:00Z
Creator Id                      : pub-creator12
Creator                         : Matt Garrish
Contributor                     : O’Reilly Production Services, David Futato, Robert Romano, Brian Sawyer, Dan Fauxsmith, Karen Montgomery
Publisher                       : O’Reilly Media, Inc.
Rights                          : Copyright © 2012 O’Reilly Media, Inc
Manifest Item Id                : htmltoc
Manifest Item Properties        : nav
Manifest Item Media-type        : application/xhtml+xml
Manifest Item Href              : bk01-toc.xhtml
Spine Itemref Idref             : cover
Spine Itemref Linear            : no
```

(here on a sample epub file from http://idpf.github.io/epub3-samples/30/samples.html)

Comment: That one works but still doesn't give version of epub. In the example you gave it does tell the version of epub.